# Rails reference to custom unique id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, database-design

This is a rails project using ActiveRecord with Postgres.

Hi I'm working with two CSVs. One is a record of all registered voters in the state. When I created this table I didn't use a generated unique id as an indexed column, but instead used the already assigned state state_voter_id. Schema for Voter table:

```
create_table "voters", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "state_voter_id", null: false
 t.string "county_voter_id"
 t.string "first_name"
 t.string "middle_name"
 t.string "last_name"
 t.string "suffix"
 t.string "birthdate"
 t.string "gender"
 t.string "add_st_num"
 t.string "add_st_name"
 t.string "add_st_type"
 t.string "add_unit_type"
 t.string "add_pre_direction"
 t.string "add_post_direction"
 t.string "add_unit_num"
 t.string "city"
 t.string "state"
 t.string "zip"
 t.string "county"
 t.string "precinct"
 t.string "leg_dist"
 t.string "cong_dist"
 t.string "reg_date"
 t.string "last_vote"
 t.string "status"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.index ["city"], name: "index_voters_on_city"
 t.index ["first_name"], name: "index_voters_on_first_name"
 t.index ["last_name"], name: "index_voters_on_last_name"
 t.index ["state_voter_id"], name: "index_voters_on_state_voter_id", unique: true
 t.index ["zip"], name: "index_voters_on_zip"
end
```

I know want to add in a new table/model of vote records containing the state_voter_id as the reference to the Voter table
This is the migration I tried:

```
def change
 create_table :votes do |t|
  t.references :voter, column: :state_voter_id
  t.string :county
  t.string :date

  t.timestamps
end
```

When I ran the migration It migrated, but when I tried to start seeding voter records I got the following error: `ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey: Unknown primary key for table voters in model Voter`. I also noted that the table was set up to take a bigint.

How do I set it up so that I am properly referencing the Voter on state_voter_id, which is an alphanumeric string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
class AddPrimaryKeyToVoters < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :voters, :state_voter_id, :primary_key
  end
end
```

In your voters model add
`self.primary_key = "state_voter_id"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with your migration, it's with your Model. You need this

```
class Voter < ApplicationRecord
   self.primary_key = 'state_voter_id'
   ...
end
```

Note that's assuming Rails 5 with the new `ApplicationRecord` class. If you're using rails 4 then just inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` as usual.